# Сортировка чисел аргумента сортирован от краев самые большие в середине наименьшие

Tags: java

Прошу помогите отсортировать от краев самые большие в середине наименьшие.
Пример
вводим - 8, 1, 2, 5, 7, 12, 3
получаем - 12, 7, 3, 1, 2, 5, 8
Голову ломаю не могу понять как это сделать.
Язык программирование Java

Comment: сначала просто отсортируй, потом бери поочередно и добавляй с нужной стороны. Или бери через один и добавляй подряд

Comment: Сначала сортировать по убыванию `12,8,7,5,3,2,1`, потом разделить на 2 половины, четные индексы и не четные `12,7,3,1` и `8,5,2`, после этого четные записать в результат как есть, нечетные - в обратном порядке. `12,7,3,1`+`2,5,8` = `12,7,3,1,2,5,8`

Answer (score 0):

Похоже для решения такой задачи проще использовать дополнительную память для сортировки входного массива, который нужно затем перезаполнить по соответствующим индексам.

Вариант решения с использованием `PriorityQueue` и вычислением индексов:

- начальный индекс будет ровно середина массива для нечетной длины и меньше на 1 для четной длины массива
- затем для вычисления следующего индекса нужно будет брать знакопеременные приращения: 1, -2, 3, -4...

Реализация:

```java
public static void spiralSort(int[] arr) {
    PriorityQueue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<>(arr.length);
    for (int n : arr) {
        q.add(n);
    }
    
    for (int i = arr.length / 2 + arr.length % 2 - 1, d = 1, s = -1;
         !q.isEmpty(); i += (s *= -1) * d++) 
    {
        arr[i] = q.poll();
    }
}
```

Тесты:

```java
int[][] tests = {
    {8, 1, 2, 5, 7, 12, 3},
    {8, 1, 2, 5, 7, 12, 3, 11},
    {1},
    {3, 1}
};
for (int[] arr : tests) {
    System.out.println("before: " + Arrays.toString(arr));
    spiralSort(arr);
    System.out.println("sorted: " + Arrays.toString(arr));
    System.out.println("----");
}
```

Результаты:

```
before: [8, 1, 2, 5, 7, 12, 3]
sorted: [12, 7, 3, 1, 2, 5, 8]
----
before: [8, 1, 2, 5, 7, 12, 3, 11]
sorted: [11, 7, 3, 1, 2, 5, 8, 12]
----
before: [1]
sorted: [1]
----
before: [3, 1]
sorted: [1, 3]
----
```

Comment: накатал пример без доп памяти

Comment: Спасибо. Я долго голову ломал уже не выдержал и попросил помощи не думал что так быстро кто то ответит мне.

Comment: @Gvad, если какой-то из ответов оказался полезным, поставьте зеленую галочку и/или проголосуйте за него.

Answer (score 0):

Я решу на C#, переведете на джаву сами.
Чтобы сделать подобное прямо на месте, без доп памяти, нужно:

Определить метод для обмена переменными в массиве

```
private void swap(int[] data, int i, int j)
{
    var tmp = data[i];
    data[i] = data[j];
    data[j] = tmp;
}
```

Потом сам алгоритм

```
var arr = new int[] { 12, 8, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1 };
// Сортируем массив по убыванию
Array.Sort(arr, Comparer<int>.Create((x, y) => y.CompareTo(x)));

// разделяем, четные слева, нечетные справа. 
// По сути я иду по нечетным слева и меняю их на четные справа

var leftOdd = 0;
var rightEven = arr.Length - 1;

while (leftOdd < rightEven)
{
    if (leftOdd % 2 == 0) leftOdd++;
    if (rightEven % 2 != 0) rightEven--;
    swap(arr, leftOdd, rightEven);
    leftOdd += 2;
    rightEven -= 2;
}

// Заново сортируем левую часть по убыванию
Array.Sort(arr, 0, arr.Length - arr.Length / 2, Comparer<int>.Create((x, y) => y.CompareTo(x)));

// А вот правую часть сортируем по возрастанию
Array.Sort(arr, arr.Length - arr.Length / 2, arr.Length / 2, Comparer<int>.Create((x, y) => x.CompareTo(y)));

// Выводим результат
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", arr));
```

Вывод

```
12 7 3 1 2 5 8
```

Comment: Большое спасибо вы очень помогли мне.